# Remove duplicates from array and remove the same index from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I have 2 arrays, one array contains prices and the other one dates. I want to remove all duplicate prices , and I want to remove the same indexes of the date array.
How would one do this?

An example of my arrays:

```
['2022-06-27', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-03', '2022-07-04', '2022-07-05']
 [3.79, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 4.36]
```

end result needed:

```
 ['2022-06-27', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-05']
 [3.79, 4.29, 4.36]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop, splicing along the way all the duplicates found using arr.lastIndexOf(item).

```js
var arr2 = ['2022-06-27', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-03', '2022-07-04', '2022-07-05'];
var arr1 = [3.79, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 4.36];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  var current = arr1[i];
  var lastIndex = arr1.lastIndexOf(current);
  while (lastIndex > i) {
    arr1.splice(lastIndex, 1);
    arr2.splice(lastIndex, 1);
    lastIndex = arr1.lastIndexOf(current);
  }
}
console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

###### You can try this approach:

```js
const dates = ['2022-06-27', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-03', '2022-07-04', '2022-07-05'] 
const arr = [3.79, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 4.36];

const arrSet = new Set(arr);
const relatedDates = [...arrSet].map((value) => dates[arr.indexOf(value)]);

console.log([...arrSet]);
console.log(relatedDates);
```

###### Output:

```bash
[3.79, 4.29, 4.36]
['2022-06-27', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-05']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the values of a hash table with prices as keys as filtered indices. Then map dates and prices as result.

```js
const
    dates = ['2022-06-27', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-03', '2022-07-04', '2022-07-05'],
    prices = [3.79, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 4.36],
    indices = Object
        .values(prices.reduce((r, p, i) => (r[p] ??= i, r), {}))
        .sort((a, b) => a - b),
    datesNew = indices.map(i => dates[i]),
    pricesNew = indices.map(i => prices[i]);

console.log(...datesNew);
console.log(...pricesNew);
```